# JParameter parameter not found while upgrading joomla 1.5 to joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla1.5, joomla2.5

i have some issue while upgrading my joomla version
my current version is joomla 1.5 upgrade using **jupgrade** to joomla2.5
it copy my template file to joomla2.5 but i have error while access front end of sites

```
Fatal error: Class 'JParameter' not found in index.php on line 151
```

in demo.php line 151 has following code

```
$jparams = new JParameter(''); $jparams->set( 'menutype', 'mainmenu' );
$hmenu = new hm_Base ($jparams); $hmenu->removeMenu();
```

give me any suggestion to avoid this type of errors

Comment: You shouldn't have to import anything if you've got the Joomla framework loaded properly. What is demo.php?

Comment: my joomla frame work is loaded succesfully , i edit my questing 'domo.php' to 'index.php' it my template default file

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Brent Friar,i have one site all ready working in joomla 1.5 frame work now i want to upgrade that site into joomla 2.5 and i got above error while my template access

Comment: Right, but what is the original code trying to do here? What does the class hm_Base do? There are some changes in 1.6+ that would cause the problem, but I am not really sure what the code is doing here so I don't know what needs to change.

Answer (score 4):

Jparameter is deprecated on joomla 2.5. use Jform instead, read http://docs.joomla.org/Upgrading_a_Joomla_1.5_extension_to_Joomla_1.6#Accessing_component_parameters_in_front-end

Comment: this article really gud , +1 for it

Answer (score 2):

Add `jimport( 'joomla.html.parameter' );` to the top of the file
(probably right after the rest of your **jimport** statements

Answer (score 1):

Just change it to this:

```
$jparams = new JRegistry(''); $jparams->set( 'menutype', 'mainmenu' );
$hmenu = new hm_Base ($jparams); $hmenu->removeMenu();
```

Works fine for me...